# How is byte addressing implemented in modern computers?

Tags: cpu, cpu-architecture

I have trouble understanding how in say a 32-bit computer byte addressing is achieved:

Is the ram itself byte addressable meaning the first byte has address 0 and the second 1 etc? In this case, wouldn't is take 4 read cycles to read a 32-bit word and waste the width of the data bus?

Or does the ram consist of 32-bit words meaning address 0 points to the first 4 bytes and address 2 points to bytes 5 to 8? In this case I would expect the ram interface to make byte addressing possible (from the cpu's  point of view)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of RAM as 8 bit wide structure with N entries. N is often the size quoted when referring to memory (256 MB - 256M entries, 2GB - 2G entries etc, B is for bytes). When you access this memory, the smallest unit you can address is one of these entries which is 8 bits (1 byte). Since you can only access it at byte level, we call it byte addressable memory.

Now coming to your question about accessing this memory, we do not just access a byte. Most of the time, memory accesses are sent through caches which are there to reduce memory access latency. Caches store data at a higher granularity than a byte or word, normally it is multiple of words. In doing so, caches explore a property called "locality". Locality means, there is a high chance that we either access this data item or a near by data item very soon. So fetching not just the byte, but all the adjacent bytes is not a waste. Think of it as an investment for future, saves you multiple data fetches that you would have done otherwise.

Answer (score -1):

Memory addresses in RAM start with 0th address and they are accessed using the registers with capacity of 8 bit register or 32 bit registers. Based on these registers the value from specific address is accessed by the CPU. If you really need to understand how it works, you will need to run couple of programs using Assembly language to navigate in the physical memory by reading the values directly using registers and register move commands.